# Will removing a google account from a device delete the game data?

Tags: google

I have an android phone from my friend because i need to get some game data with a code from my old account for a game. The thing is, he is logged in his account rn. If i go to settings,google then accounts and i remove his account will his game data be wiped? If yes,when i login back with his account will his data be back or no? Please anawer quickly, i dont have much time. and btw i cant acces my google play account because i use ios.

Comment: It depends on the game, but it **will** delete some other non-game data, so don't do it. Why not just add your account without removing his account?

Answer (score 1):

different games have different ways to save.
most games have their save on google cloud, and some game place it on private server, or local storage.
Most western (google play requiring games) store their saves in google server, meanwhile eastern have their own server for save.

why dont you mention your game title for a better understanding?
because different game have different rule